# Azuredevops bash task error - Error: open /dev/tty: no such device or address

Tags: bash, shell, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am able to successfully execute the below command locally within the agent machine

```
aztfy resource-group -n --full-properties my-rg
```

Here My AzureDevops Build agent machine is redhat and I installed aztfy by downloading the archive and copied this to /usr/local/bin directory. Assigned 777 permission for the user which is executing the pipeline. But when i try to execute same within Azuredevops pipeline, its getting failed.

```
  - stage: stage1
    displayName: stage1
    pool:
        name: mypool
    jobs:
      - job: Import_Current_terraform_manifests_RG_Level
        steps:
        - script: |
            mkdir -p '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terrafy'
            cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terrafy
            echo "creating terraform manifests"
            `aztfy resource-group -n --full-properties my-rg`
```

Azuredevops task of both types bash and scripts giving unexpected errors as below.

```
Error: open /dev/tty: no such device or address

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'
```

if I add quotes to the command, then the error will be as below.

```
/agent-1/_work/_temp/xxxxxxxx.sh: line 7: /usr/local/bin/aztfy resource-group -n --full-properties "my-rg": No such file or directory
```

I found that  the command is working till "aztfy rg --non-interactive --full-properties " and when i append the command with the resource-group name only its failing. "aztfy rg --non-interactive --full-properties my-rg"/ I tried with multiple ways like passing the full resource id, or with quotes and passing the --subscription-id parameters, etc.. but no luck

Comment: why are you using backquotes around your azure command ?

Comment: else I am getting the first error "Error: open /dev/tty: no such device or address

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'"

Comment: Where execute the command locally within the agent machine? And you can try to "cd" the same path in pipeline to check if it works.

Comment: Yes, Both cases tested already, manually I am able to execute this command there. Also in the pipeline I am able create the directory and navigate to there

Comment: I found that  the command is working till "aztfy rg --non-interactive --full-properties " and when i append the command with the resource-group name only its failing. "aztfy rg --non-interactive --full-properties my-rg"/ I tried with multiple ways like passing the full resource id, or with quotes and passing the --subscription-id parameters, etc.. but no luck

Comment: It seems, this is due t some tty feature issue. somehow the Azuredevops bash tasks is not able to run the command with the tty error. I checked the tty permission and everything seems fine. Is there any solution for this?